# Not sort array using PHP

Tags: php, sorting

I have PHP code that sort an array:

```
arsort($chart);
```

but I do not want to sort it, have any solution that make it unsorted? `sort oppossite unsort` so does it have function unsort()?

Comment: Just remove `arsort($chart);` from the code?

Comment: Do you want to have a random order? Please make an example of what result you want.

Comment: The exact opposite? As in array_reverse(asort($chart))?

Comment: shuffle($chart); http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Comment: You could replace it with yoghurt? That's *almost*, but not *entirely* unlike sorting it.

Comment: Can you build a building and then demolish it to get the *exact* original raw materials? **No.**

Comment: a variation of my above post: `function unsort(&$arr){shuffle($arr);}` now you have `unsort()` O.O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`shuffle($chart)`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) to randomize the order inside an array.

Answer (score 1):

Create a copy of orginal array before sort ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
        <?php
       function cmp($a, $b)
    {
        if ($a == $b) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
    }

    $a = array(3, 2, 5, 6, 1);

    usort($a); // this is the unsort function

    foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
        echo "$key: $value\n";
    }

        ?>

       0: 3 
       1: 2
       2: 5
       3: 6
       4: 1
// yuo can user with user defined function 
<?php
function my_sort($a, $b)
  {
  if ($a == $b) return 0;
  return ($a > $b) ? -1 : 1;
  }

$arr = array("Peter", "glenn","Cleveland",
"peter","cleveland", "Glenn");

usort($arr, "my_sort");

print_r ($arr);
?>
```

Comment: In what way does this answer the question? This looks like `sort()` to me.

Comment: sorry i wrote wrong result...now its work fine ..

Comment: usort() needs the 2nd argument which is the callback function. If you are going to copy this example http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php#function.usort.examples.basic I don't see how you missed it.